# URL Rewriting not work on Wamp Server

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, rewriting

I've a problem with Wamp Server and URL Rewriting. 
I've import my project from production server with his **.htaccess**.
The URL Rewriting work fine on production, but not in localhost.

In my Wamp configuration, **rewrite_module** is activate. In the httpd.conf :

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride all

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
#    Require local
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But, on my website, the link http://localhost/conditions return an 404 error. 
My .htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# Conditions
RewriteRule ^conditions  pages/conditions.php [L]
```

All files are in the wamp's root (c:/wamp/www/).

Help :(

Comment: Possible spelling error? `RewriteRule ^conditions$  /pages/conditions.php [L]`. I just woke up so, you know ;)

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located in `C:/`?

Answer (score 2):

In `httpd.conf` , have you the **line** where there is:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

If yes, remove the `#`.

Maybe you **have to create** a **virtual** host with an alias for your local application.

Follow this link [here](http://blog.smarchal.com/creer-un-virtualhost-avec-wampserver) in this case.

Maybe you have already a virtual host and aliases who need to be disabled. Check in your files *(hosts files, conf files etc...)*.

Comment: The line **LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so** was already uncomment.

And i haven't virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t create htaccess file with windows explorer.
You should create a new file in notepad and save as .htaccess